# How do I use n1-standard-1 machinetype in flexible environment (via yaml file)?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

The resources tag in app.yaml allows me to define cpu, memory and disk size.

`# extract for app.yaml file
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3.75`

Let disk be default.

This should resolve to n1-standard-1 but it actually launches n1-standard-2 machines. (see machine types: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#predefined_machine_types).

However if I reduce memory to 3 above; I can launch a n1-standard-1 machine type.

`# extract for app.yaml file
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3`

Is this a bug or do I need to correct my understanding?

Comment: I'd be curious to know what happens if you put something like `3.74` for `memory_gb`.

Comment: I am expecting it to work - maybe I should be filing a bug instead of posting a question. I will try it later sometime.

Comment: The GAE environment reserves around ~400mb for itself

Comment: could be the reason... is there a link to point out to the same.